# Proper way to position :before pseudo-elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

What is the proper way to position `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, like pictures? I've been messing around with a bunch of different ways, but none of them seem like very elegant solutions.

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

This is what I did:

```
div.read-more a:before {
    content: url('/images/read_more_arrow_sm.png');
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: -15px;
}

<div class="read-more">
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
</div>
```

I basically just want the image to be aligned with the text.  Is there another way to do that?

It would be perfect if I could just use padding and margins on the `:before` image, and that is *supposed* to be what you do.  But for some reason, that hasn't been working for me.  I can add horizontal padding and margins, but top and bottom padding doesn't do anything.  Why would that happen?

Comment: Why not give the `a` the background image and add some left padding instead?

Comment: Unless you have dozens/hundreds of these per page, I think you would be better to forget about the pseudo element and instead just position the image and the link next two each other.

Comment: Is the text in your example the "Watch Video" and the `:before` content the arrow? Why not use a background image? Please post your HTML markup.

Comment: I just added the html, I suppose the bg image isn't a bad idea.  I've been a little pseudo-crazy ever since I learned about them.  Do you know any pros and cons to either method?

Comment: @Calley Nye: The only real difference is that IE < 8 doesn't support `:before/:after`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using `background` instead of `content` and put a placeholder in `content`:

```css
div.read-more a:before {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyerX.jpg') CENTER CENTER NO-REPEAT;
  content: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icd9n.png');
  /* 21x21 transparent pixels */
  width: 21px;
  height: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="read-more">
  <a href="#">Read More</a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7X7x2/1/

Comment: a slight change that works and doesn't have to worry about background image and doesn't add extra space to top. div.read-more a:before {
    content: url('http://i.stack.imgur.com/XyerX.jpg');
    width:21px;
    height:21px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

Comment: This answer is 10 years old and I hardly participate on StackOverflow anymore. Anyone with sufficient reputation is free to edit and should do so if they feel it enriches the site and the community.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen on an off-note - apologies for bothering you, the thread came to scrutiny due to my request for removing one of the duplicate answers. P.s. Note for everyone: there were no runnable snippets back in late 2011 (the feature is from circa 2014).

Answer (score 45):

You can use the following code in order to move the content:

```
div.read-more a:before {
  content: "\00BB \0020";
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want only to position image near the text, then you probably need the `vertical-align` property:

```css
div.read-more a:before {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    content: url(image.png);
}
```

It has the following possible values: `baseline`, `sub`, `super`, `top`, `text-top`, `middle`, `bottom`, `text-bottom`

These values are calculated from the position of the text from the current text line (Read more in the example).

Full reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

(To add space before text just use margin-right)

Comment: Seems totally ineffective for :before, :after elements (Chrome 59). Not sure why this answer has rep. as it is obvious it's unlikely to work for this particular context

Comment: @Smithfield work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/p8y6fv8h/ can you make the gist there it didn't work?

Comment: @Alexey Ivanov indeed, so much for me and thanks for the fiddle! Although it's not working on my side, I can't link it. I only have trails on why it's not working - the line-height property: if too small also seems to affect the rendering, my :after is also deeply nested in a span within a link within a table cell within..., all of which have particular properties constraining the final element.

Answer (score 2):

This was my solution, with a mouseover:

```
div.read-more a:before {
    content: url(image.png);
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    left: -7px;
    padding-left: 7px;
}
div.read-more a:hover:before {
    content: url(image_hover.png);
}
```

Comment: This works, however adds some extra space in the focus state of the element your'e styling which looks a bit odd.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the easiest way to position these is using the flex container.

Bring in the image using background image, give it the required width and height, and make sure the the image is contained. Doing this controls the size, regardless of how big the image in your url is(compared to the uncontrolled approach in `content:url()`)

```
div.read-more a:before {
    content:'';
    background-image: url('/images/read_more_arrow_sm.png');
    width:25px; //or any size you prefer
    height:25px;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

And on the container element, which in your case is the anchor tag,

```
<div class="read-more">
    <a href="#">Read More</a>
</div>
```

declare a flex container

```
div.readmore a{
    display: inline-flex; //or simply 'flex', whatever works for you
    align-items:center;
}
```

This approach using flexbox is much more intuitive than using arbitrary pixel values using `position:absolute` and `top`/`left` keywords.